# Ignore case Sensitiveness of Jquery AJAX call URL

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-services

Currently, I am working on Asp.net 3.5 project and I am calling a Webservice by ajax call

```
$.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "WebService/DefaultPage.asmx/GetTours",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                Home.ReadTours(data);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $('.load-3').hide();
            }
        });
```

working fine.

but when I change the URL to lowercase.

```
url: "webservice/defaultpage.asmx/gettours",
```

its not working.

Is this Jquery Ajax URL is case sensitive and is there any by I can ignore case sensitiveness of ajax URL.

Comment: Why are you changing the URL to lowercase?

Comment: url: "webservice/defaultpage.asmx/GetTours"

Comment: there is some reason due to which i have to change my url...but question is here is not why i am changing url...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Image from the server while ignoring the file's case sensitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329925/getting-image-from-the-server-while-ignoring-the-files-case-sensitivity)

Comment: If using IIS, should not pose an issue, unless it is happening because of the parameter case(/gettours vs. /GetTours) which is handled by the application, see http://forums.iis.net/t/1165661.aspx/1

Comment: @Dror means i have to change function name GetTours to gettours..

Comment: I mean, IIS (which is hosting the application) is not case sensitive, but application is (and thus may not recognize gettours, only GetTours). Suggest you try to invoke with webservice/defaultpage.asmx/GetTours and see if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your server fielding the ajax request will need to be configured to NOT be case sensitive.  There is nothing you can do in the client to change case sensitivity of a server (other than providing the case that the server expects).