# get stuck with how to disable case sensitive in apache 2.2.22 ubuntu

Tags: apache, magento, ubuntu-12.04

Help me guys,

I've been long time after i migrate my magento 1.4 to my new server of ubuntu, i just need to disable case sensitive in apache because many of my picture file character are not the same with the script.

> example:  picture : pict1.jpg, but in the script: PICT1.jpg

i had put :

> CheckSpelling on

in spelling.conf
fail

and then i tried to put

> CheckSpelling on

in .htaccess, but stil no effect. i also put that script to httpd.conf but still no effect.

from all clue that i found in internet are almost the same, using "CheckSpelling on", but not worked for me...!!!

headache, really headache. Really need your help guys..

Comment: Linux uses a case sensitive file system, and as you've found out, is Magento's expected native environment. You will have to make sure the `mod_speling.so` DSO module is loaded in Apache before you can enable it with `CheckSpelling On` as a hack to disable case sensitivity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329925/getting-image-from-the-server-while-ignoring-the-files-case-sensitivity

Comment: how do i know mod_speling.so is enabled or not?

Answer (score 0):

Look for this line in your `httpd.conf` file:

```
 #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
```

Uncomment it to enable the module. Add this line to the configuration file:

```
 CheckCaseOnly on
```

Restart *Apache*.